# how to detect all tween complete in starling-framework

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I'm develop a game with starling-framework.my problem is how to detect all tween is complete when I add a set of elements into `juggler`.

current my plan is

```
while(some_condition){ //allocate a set of tween
     var tween=createTween(tweenCount++);
     tween.onComplete=function(){
         tweenCount--;
     }
}
function checkComplete(){
     if(tweenCount==0)
        doStuff();
     else
        setTimeout(checkComplete,1000);
}
```

and there is any better solution ? thanks for your time!

### update

write a simple class to solve this ,seems like better

```
public class TweenMonitor 
{

    public function TweenMonitor() 
    {
        throw new Error('static class');
    }

    private static var refDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    public static function monit(tweens:Vector.<Tween>,onAllFinish:Function,id:String='$default$'):void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < tweens.length; i++) 
        {
            var tween:Tween = tweens[i];
            if (tween == null)
                continue;
            if (refDict[id] == null) {
                refDict[id] = 1;
            }else
                refDict[id]++;
            tween.addEventListener(Event.REMOVE_FROM_JUGGLER,function (e:Event):void 
            {
                refDict[id]--;
                if (refDict[id] == 0)
                    onAllFinish && onAllFinish();
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need the [onComplete property](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/animation/Tween.html#onComplete) of Tween Class (Starling Framework)

Here is an Example :

```
function addTween() { 

   var tween:Tween = new Tween(object, 2.0, Transitions.EASE_IN_OUT);
   tween.animate("x", object.x + 50);
   tween.animate("rotation", deg2rad(45));
   tween.fadeTo(0);   
   tween.onComplete = tween_complete;
   Starling.juggler.add(tween); 
}

function tween_complete() {

   // Handle Tween Complete Action Here   
}
```

---

**EDIT**

In case of multiple tweens, you probably could do better by attaching a timer class instead of settimeout:

```
while(some_condition){ //allocate a set of tween
     var tween=createTween(tweenCount++);
     tween.onComplete = function() { tweenCount--; }
}

var timer : Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,update);
timer.start();    

function update(e) {

     if(tweenCount > 0) return;

     timer.stop();
     timer = null;

     doStuff();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,I've update my question,note that I have a set of element but not one . so is there any better solution :)

Comment: using timer is probably a better option than the settimeout. Updated my answer...

Comment: well I accept your answer,I think use tweenCount flag is already a better plan .thanks

Comment: Why do you guys use a timer that runs every second? Sems very unnecessary

Comment: @DanielMesSer Of course it does, but only from the little bit of code that the OP exposed. Only suggested an alternative to the existing settimeout that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done like this:

```
OnComplete = tweenDone;

...

function tweenDone() {
    TweenCount--;
    If(TweenCount == 0) doStuff();
}
```

Wrote this on a cell phone so I had to take a lot of shortcuts, if you need more info, leave a comment!